# maximum product of real numbers that sum to 2009

Tags: inequality

If we use the AM GM inequality we see

$$ (a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots+a_n)/n \ge (a_1a_2a_3a_4\ldots a_n)^{1/n} $$

Hence, as we know the numbers sum to $2009$:

$$ (2009/n)^n \ge a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_n $$

Therefore the product is maximum when the numbers are all equal - the value of this product of numbers is the LHS of the above hence we have to find the maximum of the LHS = $(2009/x)^x$.

The actual answer is that we have to maximise $x^{2009/x}$  - why doesn't my method work?

Comment: By "real numbers" do you mean "positive real numbers"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to connect up your notation a bit.  Is the number of parts known or to be varied?  I think for a fixed number of parts $n$ your argument is correct and you get a conclusion of make the parts equal.

Now let $x = 2009/n$ be the size of those parts, so their product is $x^n = x^{2009/x}$ as claimed.